# leaked window in android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, window

Leaked window error .. don't know what to do .. please help me out here ..

comment your answers plss ..

```
    public class Profile extends Fragment{
int success;
View profiles;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json;
TextView tvName,tvNumber,tvEmail,tvUsername,tvPass,tvAddress,newmunber;
Button save;
String adminName, adminNumber,adminEmail,adminUsername,adminPassword,adminAddress;
String newnum;
Context context;
Dialog dialog;

private static final String PROFILE_URL =    "http://jcasim.5gbfree.com/Project/JCASIM_Api/profile.php";
private static final String CHANGES_URL = "http://jcasim.5gbfree.com/Project/JCASIM_Api/changeNum.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
// private static final String TAG_ID = "id";



public Profile (){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View profiles = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container,false);
    tvName = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminName);
    tvNumber = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminNumber);
    tvEmail = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminEmail);
    tvUsername = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminUsername);
    tvPass = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminPassword);
    tvAddress = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminAddress);
     newmunber = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.inputNum);
     save = (Button) profiles.findViewById(R.id.savenum);
     new profile().execute();

    TextView changeNumber = (TextView)profiles.findViewById(R.id.tvAdminChangNumber);
    changeNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new changenum().execute();
        }
    });

    return profiles;
}




class profile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String addminObject ="";
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addminObject", addminObject));
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "POST",params);
        try {
            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (success == 1){
            try {
                JSONArray myarr = json.getJSONArray("addminObject");

                for(int i =0; i<myarr.length();i++){
                    JSONObject s = myarr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String adminName = s.getString("CompleteName");
                       String adminNumber = s.getString("Number");
                       String adminEmail = s.getString("Email");
                       String adminUsername = s.getString("Username");
                       String adminPassword = s.getString("Password");
                       String adminAddress = s.getString("Address");


                    tvName.setText(adminName);
                    tvNumber.setText(adminNumber);
                    tvEmail.setText(adminEmail);
                    tvUsername.setText(adminUsername);
                    tvPass.setText(adminPassword);
                    tvAddress.setText(adminAddress);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Watwatwat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   

    }

}

class changenum extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    int success;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.changenum);
        dialog.setTitle("Change Number");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        newnum = newmunber.getText().toString();
        // TODO Auto-generated method s

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newNum", newnum));
        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CHANGES_URL, "POST",
                params);

        try {
            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (success == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number succesfully changed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tvNumber.setText(newnum);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Changes Failed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

            }
        });
    }
    }


}
```

here the print screen of my error log .. it refers to my other activity which is slidemenu

and heres the code from my slidemenu .

```
    public class Slidemenu extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG = Slidemenu.class.getSimpleName();
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slidemenu);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(4, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(5, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(6, -1)));

    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());


    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name 

    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navigateTo(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        navigateTo(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slidemenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void navigateTo(int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "List View Item: " + position);

    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new Logout()).commit();
        break;
    case 2:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new SalesFragment()).commit();
        break;
    case 3:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new ProductListTabs()).commit();
        break;
    case 4:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new Logout()).commit();
        break;
    case 5:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new SuppliersFragment()).commit();
        break;
    case 6:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new Profile()).commit();
        break;
    }

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

    }
```

Comment: can you post the logcat error?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added ?

Comment: maybe this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3293075/1325646

Comment: dismiss your dialog in onPostExecute() dialog.dismiss();

Comment: error is till leaked window in my slidemenu activity

Comment: i can't upload an image of error log sir adavis.

Answer (score 0):

1. `dismiss()` the `dialog` in your `changenum` asynctask `onPostExecute()`.
2. Move the member variable `Dialog dialog;` inside the asynctask so each asynctask instance has its own dialog and not possibly overwriting a variable already used by some other instance, leaving dialogs non-dismissed.